# Class not found Exception:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (RMI program not working)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**File**: *SelectServerIntf.java*:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.*;
public interface SelectServerIntf extends Remote{
   HashMap executeSelect() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**File**: *SelectServerImpl.java*:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SelectServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements SelectServerIntf {
    public SelectServerImpl() throws RemoteException
    {
    }   
    public HashMap executeSelect() throws RemoteException
    {
        String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc2";
        String Query="select * from student";
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stat=null;
        HashMap hm=null; 
        try
        {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);       
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cn)
        {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFound"+cn);
        } 
        try
        {
            con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
            stat=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(Query);
            hm=new HashMap();            
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int rno=rs.getInt(1);
                String name=rs.getString(2);
                hm.put(new Integer(rno),name);
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLException"+se);
        }
        return(hm);
    }
}
```

**File**: *SelectServer.java*:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.net.*;
public class SelectServer {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            SelectServerImpl sip=new SelectServerImpl();
            Naming.rebind("SELECT-SERVER", sip);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

**File**: *SelectClient.java*:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
public class SelectClient {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String rmiurl="rmi://"+args[0]+"/SELECT-SERVER";
        try
        {
            SelectServerIntf sit=(SelectServerIntf)Naming.lookup(rmiurl);
            HashMap hm2=sit.executeSelect();

            int sz=hm2.size();

            for(int i=1;i<sz;i++)
            {
                if(hm2.containsKey(new Integer(i)))
                    System.out.println(i+":"+hm2.get(new Integer(i)));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("Exception"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

The above RMI program on execution gives

```
"Class not found Exception:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
SQLException:No Suitable Driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc2
```

where abc2 is my database containing respective tables.

The above given connection url and drivers works properly for every code but acccept this rmi.

Experts do you find any modification??

Comment: Is the mysql jdbc driver jar file in the classpath of the application?

Comment: Driver jar file added to classpath or application/lib ?

Comment: You don't need the `Class.forName()` call with the current MySQL Connector-J. You haven't for some years actually. This is purely a CLASSPATH problem, not an RMI problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+mysql+no+suitable+driver+found

Answer (score 2):

You need to put mysql jdbc driver jars in your server's classpath. It will enable your server to load driver class while calling `executeSelect()`